# MVVM in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use this pattern MVVM pattern with the tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMQuickTutorial.aspx
It seems it might work for Visual Studio 2008 but what about Visual Studio 2010? 
I am trying to install the template  "WPF Model-View Application"  but according to some reviewers at the Codepeax project of "WPF Model-View-ViewModel Toolkit", this project appears to be dumped by Microsoft or buggy? Sorry but I am confused. I cannot get straight answers on what the best practices for developing a WPF application according to Microsoft. Is the MVVM pattern no go good for an updated Visual Studio 2010 environment using C#?

What is the best and modern pattern to use for WPF in Visual Studio 2010 using C#? Can someone send out a decent easy end to end tutorial on this? I like to download sample code and project solutions as well.
Thanks a billion

Comment: I'm not at home right now so I don't have access to VS 2010 but I'm guessing they are just doing something in that tutorial that 2010 doesn't like. I just wanted to suggest you take a look at Caliburn and/or Caliburn.Micro if you are looking to do WPF MVVM in 2010. http://caliburn.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

MVVM is a pattern, that is it's language agnostic.  You can apply it in java, c++, vb etc.
The tutorial/demo may not work in c# 4, but the principles would be the same.

Are you having problems understanding a specific point?

Comment: Well, I am trying to apply the "WPF Model-View Application" in my Visual Studio 2010. It is not working but my concern is more of the Codeplex project "WPF Model-View-ViewModel Toolkit". Is this no good anymore? What is Microsoft's best practices for WPF applications using Visual Studio 2010? I know about MVVM Light but I don't think this will integrate with Expression Blend 4. Or will it? Sorry I misread about MVVM Light for Blend. But is this supported by Microsoft? Or what do they use?

Comment: @heavy rocker dude here is a tutorial of using MVVM Light in Expression Blend: http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/creatingblend/

Comment: Wow. This looks really decent actually. Once again, I am impressed by you guys at StackOverflow!! Thanks to all!!!

Comment: MVVM heavily relies on databinding. so its not language agnostic and definitely you can not do it in C++.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent toolkit called [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) that works perfectly in Visual Studio 2010.

There is a bunch of information about it available here: http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/

This tutorial will probably be especially helpful: http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/creating/

There is also a great series from Jesse Liberty here: http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/04/wpfs-mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-part-i/

Answer (score 1):

I am using [this](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) and it works great in visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You want to try out http://mvvmpsample.codeplex.com its a VS2010 solution

Following blog posts explain what it is:

- http://www.overroot.com/blog/?p=188
- http://www.overroot.com/blog/?p=285

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/970005b8-ee15-4295-9960-375e6ea1276c) template very useful. It has some useful predefined class such as NotificationObject that handles calls to RaisePropertyChanged by passing the field itself instead of a string (very useful) as well as DelegateCommand and some Converters. It has some example XAML code to show how things are wired up as well.